# remove filename and extension name and only show folder name

Tags: php, .htaccess, hide

how can I show folder name instead of file name?

For example,
www.example.com/home/index.php -> www.example.com/home

I know when I browse www.example.com/home I will get the result but that is not what I want because it will add a / behind the folder name (e.g www.example.com/home/).

What I want is without the / behind the folder and when user browse www.example.com/home/index.php the page will redirect the user to page not found. The purpose I do this is to hide the language I used and make the link more readable and memorable.

I found something like rewrite the rules in .htaccess file but I am new in php so I don't how to make it. Anyone can give me suggestion or provides some tutorial about this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the slash, you must first disable [`DirectorySlash`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash)

```
DirectorySlash Off
DirectoryIndex disabled
```

Direct access to PHP files can be answered with a [`R=404`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) status code

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule \.php$ - [R=404,L]
```

And then, you can rewrite requests pointing to a directory and containing an `index.php`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ /$0/index.php [L]
```

This `RewriteCond` looks, if the requested URL is a directory and if there is an `index.php` in this directory. If this is the case, then the `index.php` is executed.

Putting all together

```
DirectorySlash Off
DirectoryIndex disabled

RewriteEngine on

# prevent direct access to PHP files
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule \.php$ - [R=404,L]

# rewrite requests for a directory to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ /$0/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Whatever I browse will go to page not found. Example, I have www.example.com/home/index.php and I type www.example.com/home, it displays 404 error.

Comment: @overshadow I tried these rules in my test environment and they work fine. There must be additional rules in your htaccess or some other configuration issues causing this. Maybe, browser caching `301` redirects from your previous requests.

Comment: Can you explain this two line for me? RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ /$0/index.php [L]

Comment: I found the solution. Just remove the / in front of the $0, from RewriteRule ^.*$ /$0/index.php [L] change to RewriteRule ^.*$ $0/index.php [L]. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @overshadow I tried to explain the `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` a bit, I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

Htaccess doesn't have anything common with PHP. Htaccess is Apache's configuration file, so you need to play with htaccess to achieve that what you want. On the other hand your solution will be really dirty. Learn about MVC and FrontController to make your structure cleaner.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks. Do you have any materials about MVC and FrontController for sharing with me?